# Indents of section*{} name in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script

I have some sections (e.g. References) that don't have a section number. However, I'd like to include them in the TOC with \addcontentsline{toc}. But how can this manually added section be aligned to all other sections in the TOC. So probably I need the indentatoin space that is reserved for the section numbers and at it to \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{definedspace}Test Section One Three}.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test Section One Three}
\section*{Test Section One Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Test Section One Three}`

Comment: Note also that `\addcontentsline` should go *after* `\section*`, because otherwise the entry in the table of contents could be off by one.

Answer (score 5):

Use option `toc=indentunnumbered` to setup the table of contents to indent entries without number and command `\addsec` to add such sections automatically to the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[toc=indentunnumbered]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}

\addsec{Test Section One Three}

\end{document}
```

Maybe you need [current KOMA-Script version](http://www.komascript.de/current) to be able to use option `toc=indentunnumbered`.