# Remove section number from table of contents in `scrartcl`

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

How to remove the section number ("1" in the example below) in the toc of `scrartcl`?

- it does not matter if the section number is or is not stated in the text (I already know how to remove it there).
- I know, I could use a starred section and manually add it to the toc, but in my real document, I use them for something else with a different format

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\KOMAoption{sectionentrydots}{true}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{non-star section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related (but maybe not same): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197991, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192902, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171831, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  %tocnumwidth=0pt,
  tocentrynumberformat=\gobbleentrynumber
]{section}
\newcommand*\gobbleentrynumber[1]{}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{non-star section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you uncomment `tocnumwidth=0pt`:

[image]

But I would use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{
  sectionentrydots=true,
  toc=indenttextentries
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addsec{non-star section}
\end{document}
```

with or without `toc=indenttextentries`.